# Добавить класс к миниатюре для товаров которых нет в наличии (в категории товаров) woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Добавить класс ко всем миниатюрам получается, а сделать условие: только для тех что нет в наличии не могу.
Пробовал так:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'AddThumbnailClass', 10, 2);
function AddThumbnailClass( $atts, $attachment ) {
    global $product;
    if(!$product->is_purchasable() ){
        $atts['class'] .= " categ-img";
    } else $atts['class'] .= "";
    
    return $atts;
}
```

не работает.

Comment: через этот фильтр вы явно ничего не сделаете, почему нельзя пользоваться тем что woocommerce добавляет класс 'featured' для тега 'li' когда товара нет в наличии?

Comment: Да, у li есть класс outofstock/instock попробую через него

Answer (score 0):

Состояние товара вы можете получить использовав метод `get_stock_status`. Если товара нет в наличии он равен `outofstock`

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'add_thumbnail_class' );
function add_thumbnail_class( $attributes ) {

    global $product;
    if ( ! $product->is_purchasable() ) {
        $attributes['class'] .= " categ-img";
    }
    if ( 'outofstock' === $product->get_stock_status() ) {
        $attributes['class'] .= " product-out-of-stock";
    }

    return $attributes;
}
```

Подробнее https://woocommerce.wp-a2z.org/oik_api/wc_productget_stock_status/

Comment: все не плохо кроме одного момента, woocommerce_is_purchasable не используется для изменния атрибутов миниатюры, https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-product-external.html#source-view.151

Comment: @DarthKYL причем тут это? У пользователя работает этот код) он не знал как определить сток статус товара. Вопрос читайте